# C++ File System

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, filesystems

I am trying to add these functions.

```
std::string GetDirectory(std::string path_name) {
    boost::filesystem::path path(path_name.c_str());

    path_name = path.string();

    path_name.erase(
        path_name.substr(
            path_name.find_last_of(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR),
            path_name.length()
        )
    );
    return path_name;
}

std::string GetName(std::string path_name) {
    boost::filesystem::path path(path_name.c_str());

    path_name = path.string();

    path_name.erase(
        path_name.substr(
            0, 
            path_name.find_last_of(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR)
        )
    );

    path_name.erase(
        path_name.substr(
            path_name.find_last_of("."), 
            path_name.length()
        )
    );
    return path_name;
}

std::string GetExtension(std::string path_name) {
    boost::filesystem::path path(path_name.c_str());

    path_name = path.string();

    path_name.erase(
        path_name.substr(
            0, 
            path_name.find_last_of('.')
        )
    );
    return path_name;
}
```

I am trying to add:

> C:\Windows\Users\Example\Desktop\test.txt

GetDirectory

> C:\Windows\Users\Example\Desktop

GetName

> test

GetExtension

> txt

I get errors though between path_name and erase (the period).
Help would be much appreciated, Thank you.

Please requested error messages:

> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(368,5): warning MSB8004: Output Directory does not end with a trailing slash.  This build instance will add the slash as it is required to allow proper evaluation of the Output Directory.
>   1>  main.cpp
>   1>main.cpp(287): error C2664: 'std::_String_iterator>> std::basic_string,std::allocator>::erase(std::_String_const_iterator>>,std::_String_const_iterator>>)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::basic_string,std::allocator>' to 'unsigned int'
>   1>  main.cpp(287): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
>   1> main.cpp(301): error C2664: 'std::_String_iterator>> std::basic_string,std::allocator>::erase(std::_String_const_iterator>>,std::_String_const_iterator>>)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::basic_string,std::allocator>' to 'unsigned int'
>   1>  main.cpp(301): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
>   1> main.cpp(307): error C2664: 'std::_String_iterator>> std::basic_string,std::allocator>::erase(std::_String_const_iterator>>,std::_String_const_iterator>>)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::basic_string,std::allocator>' to 'unsigned int'
>   1>  main.cpp(307): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
>   1> main.cpp(321): error C2664: 'std::_String_iterator>> std::basic_string,std::allocator>::erase(std::_String_const_iterator>>,std::_String_const_iterator>>)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::basic_string,std::allocator>' to 'unsigned int'
>   1>  main.cpp(321): note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called

Comment: "I get errors" - and more precisely?

Comment: Posted error messages.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

- Delete useless and harmful `path_name.substr(` and `)`.
- You can omit the second argument of `std::string::erase` to erase until the end of string.

Comment: Did not work, crashes program, but thanks for the response.

Got rid of substr and length.

Comment: @MichaelKilpatrick Although the output was wrong, [the program without boost](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/MeDc8xpCxEIb0yNJ) didn't crash.

Comment: Thank you, so boost was the issue?

Comment: @MichaelKilpatrick [Program using boost](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/hKRzHjwFMXsfjDrZ) also exited normally with wrong result.

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
template <class Path> typename Path::string_type extension(const Path& p);
```

function to get the extension.

And you should use

```
template <class Path> typename Path::string_type basename(const Path& p);
```

function to get the base name of the file.

I assume you are using Windows OS.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

int main()
{
    namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

    std::string p = "C:\\Windows\\Users\\Example\\Desktop\\test.txt";

    std::string ext = fs::extension(p);
    std::string bas = fs::basename(p);

    std::cout << ext << " " << bas << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm new at C++ can you give me an example?
Thank you for the response.